# Connecting to Git team provider failed

Tags: git, maven, debugging

Im trying to define a maven project through version control, but my error log describes a problem with the git team provider.

```
> Error connecting project MyProject, suggested path
> 'C:\folder\potato\eclipseprojects\potatoclock\.git' do not match found
> Git repositories '[RepositoryMapping[<empty> -> '../.git', absolute
> path: 'C:/eclipseprojects/eclipseprojects/.git' ]]'.
```

It's noticable in the  that eclipse doesn't map the path right. Let's take a look at **the steps I leading to the error above**

1. Open Eclipse and pick a workspace which fits you best. For this project, assume that you make a new workspace to keep it simple
2. start with importing the repository by making a project with git setup
3. fill in the URI
4. press finish and wait until the loading bar in the lower right corner indicates the completion of the cloning process
5. A wizard panel pops up. Proceed by creating a new maven project
6. select maven-archetype-quickstart and click next
7. Define the hierarchial names for the modules and the underlying artifact. 
   Let’s Assume the following definition decsribed below the module

code:

```
  GroupId:       com.example

    Artifact Id:   potatoclock

    Version:       1.0.-SNAPSHOT

    package:       com.example.potatoclock
```

Is this my fault, or a legitimate [eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519140)? let me know! An secondly, is there a simple solution or workaround? I'm looking forward to find the solution

thanks for reading!

> **Update:** I wrongfully tagged Eclipse at first. I'm using Webclipse from Genuitec. So I removed the Eclipse tag

.

> Additional information:
>
> - using JRE 1.8.0_171, Webclipse march 2018 version and Windows 10.
> - I'm using eclipse alot for creating jersey based webapps

Comment: The mentioned bug occurs when importing a project in a way that is not recommended. Please describe the steps you used and where you get the error log (which seems to be truncated). Please report WebClipse bugs to Genuitec, not to Eclipse.

Comment: The following online tool (which also supports French to English) has often been useful for me when doing a translation: https://www.deepl.com/translator

Comment: Thanks for the link. That will come useful. Anyhow, I just updated my question

Comment: Did you by any chance noticed the changes in my question? I provided 7 steps and changed the tag.

Comment: I don't use Genuitec software because it doesn't meet my requirements (I have tested Webclips once and it was slow and buggy; even worse, after a few days features of Eclipse and other open source projects were disabled, and I was prompted to pay for it). I prefer [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) instead. The recommended way is to first create a Maven project and then right-click the project and choose _Team > Share Project..._ to move it to an existing or new Git repository.

Comment: I understand your decision. However, I can recommend you the latest version of eclipse. It's faster and far less buggy. Use a clean Eclipse 12-2018 version. Thanks or the suggestion. I'll close this post now. You answered my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of Howgler worked for me. I close this post with his answer:

The recommended way is to first create a Maven project and then right-click the project and choose Team > Share Project... to move it to an existing or new Git repository. – howlger